# How to parameterize a SPARQL query in SWI Prolog?

Tags: prolog, sparql, swi-prolog, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am having difficulty making the following SPARQL query parametric.

First I load the request library:

```
?- use_module(library(semweb/sparql_client)).
%   library(uri) compiled into uri 0.02 sec, 290,256 bytes
%   library(readutil) compiled into read_util 0.00 sec, 17,464 bytes
%   library(socket) compiled into socket 0.00 sec, 11,936 bytes
%   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 14,288 bytes
%   library(base64) compiled into base64 0.00 sec, 17,912 bytes
%   library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.00 sec, 21,864 bytes
%  library(http/http_open) compiled into http_open 0.03 sec, 438,368 bytes
%   library(sgml) compiled into sgml 0.00 sec, 39,480 bytes
%     library(quintus) compiled into quintus 0.00 sec, 23,896 bytes
%    rewrite compiled into rewrite 0.01 sec, 35,336 bytes
%    library(record) compiled into record 0.00 sec, 31,368 bytes
%   rdf_parser compiled into rdf_parser 0.01 sec, 132,840 bytes
%    library(gensym) compiled into gensym 0.00 sec, 4,792 bytes
%   rdf_triple compiled into rdf_triple 0.00 sec, 39,672 bytes
%  library(rdf) compiled into rdf 0.01 sec, 244,240 bytes
% library(semweb/sparql_client) compiled into sparql_client 0.04 sec, 707,080 bytes
true.
```

I have this query that, as you can see, seems work well:

```
?- sparql_query('select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "Pescara"@it.}', Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')]).
Row = row(literal(type('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer', '1'))).
```

My problem is that I want this query to be parametric. In the previous example I have a `Pescara` value is fixed and should be a variable. I have something like:

```
?- Place = 'Roma'
```

and in the query:

```
 ?- sparql_query('select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label $Place@it.}', Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')]).
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`atom_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_concat/3)  and [`atomic_list_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3).

```
:- val('select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label $Place@it.}').

12 ?- Z='rdfs:label $', val(X), atom_concat(A,B,X), atom_concat(Z,C,B), 
      atom_concat('Place',D,C), Place='"Roma"', 
      atomic_list_concat([A,Z,Place,D],R).
.....
Place = '"Roma"',
R = 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label $"Roma"@it.}' ;
false.
```

and then

```
?- sparql_query($R, Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')]).
```

Or, simply,

```
makeQuery(Place, Query, Row) :-   %% e.g. Place = '"Rome"'
    atomic_list_concat( [ 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;',
      ' rdfs:label $', Place, '@it.}'], Query),
    sparql_query(Query, Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')] ).
```

Comment: tnx so much...actually I need a predicate that generate this query, something like buildQuery(Place, Query) where Place is the variable to insert in the query string Query, now I am trying to use your example to do it by myself...but if for you is not a problem and can show me this version I will be very grateful to you because I hurry to deliver this project to my teacher :-/

Comment: mmm the makeQuery/3 predicate go into error and say me:
?- makeQuery("Roma", Query, Row).
ERROR: atomic_list_concat/2: Type error: `text' expected, found `[82,111,109,97]

Comment: not `"Roma"`, `'"Roma"'`. Look closely into the code in my answer.

Comment: Ok, tnx you so much, now I will study your predicate...so simply I have to put the place vvaue into '"Place name"' ?

Comment: `?- makeQuery('"Roma"', Query, Row).`. call it like this.

Comment: Ok, and if I need that the makeQuery/3 predicate will be called by another predicate and not into the Prolog shell? is it good?

Comment: tweak it as you please. copy/paste bits of code. reassemble parts into new predicates. try it. If something doesn't work as you expect it, ask a question, with the code attached to it. :)

Comment: I will try to play with it in my future code, to do exercise I have tried to implement a personal version of this predicate using only append/3 predicate but seems don't work...I have open a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833316/some-doubts-creating-a-sparql-parameterized-query-using-append-3-predicate-my-v

If you have time and if this is not a problem for you can you give me your opinion? :-)