# Creating a SPARQL parameterized query using append/3 predicate

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sparql

Related to my previous post: [How to parameterize a SPARQL query in SWI Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820606/how-to-parameterize-a-sparql-query-in-swi-prolog/16822345?noredirect=1#comment24256405_16822345)

In order to exercise, I was trying to implement a predicate that builds and executes a SPARQL query using only the **append/3** predicate (differently from the solution proposed in my old post) but it doesn't work well.

This is my predicate:

```prolog
buildQuery(Place, Query, Row) :- 

    % Q1 = 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "
    Q1 = [39, 115, 101, 108, 101, 99, 116, 32, 67, 79, 85, 78, 84, 40, 42, 41, 32, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 32, 123, 63, 112, 108, 97, 99, 
              101, 32, 97, 32, 100, 98, 112, 101, 100, 105, 97, 45, 111, 119, 108, 58, 80, 108, 97, 99, 101, 32, 59, 32, 114, 100, 102, 115, 58,
              108, 97, 98, 101, 108, 32, 34],
    append(Q1, Place, Q2),
    %End = @en }}'
    End = [34, 64, 105, 116, 32, 125, 39],

    append(Q2, End, Query),
    sparql_query(Query, Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')] ).
```

Because I have found some problem inserting the **"** character directly into a string. (That is, putting **"** into  `""`; maybe I can put a **"** character into the `""` that represents the beginning and the end of a string by escaping it in some way.  I don't know.)

I am trying to build my query in the following way:
In Prolog a string is a list of ASCII characters, so I have created a **string\list Q1** that represents the string: `'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "`, which is the first part of my query.  Then I append to it the value of the **Place** variable that will be a string that represents a place (for example, `"Roma"`), creating the new string **Q2**.  Then I append the **End** string to Q2 creating the final query **Query**, where **end** is the last part of my query: **%End = @en }}'**  Finally, I execute the SPARQL query by **sparql_query/3** built in predicate, passing to it my final query, **Query**, and the other two parameters needed (as in the previous post's good working example).

The problem is that it seems not work. In the Prolog shell I execute the following command:

1. To load the needed SPARQL library:

   ```
   ?- use_module(library(semweb/sparql_client)).
   %   library(uri) compiled into uri 0.02 sec, 290,256 bytes
   %   library(readutil) compiled into read_util 0.00 sec, 17,464 bytes
   %   library(socket) compiled into socket 0.00 sec, 11,936 bytes
   %   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 14,288 bytes
   %   library(base64) compiled into base64 0.01 sec, 17,912 bytes
   %   library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.00 sec, 21,864 bytes
   %  library(http/http_open) compiled into http_open 0.03 sec, 438,368 bytes
   %   library(sgml) compiled into sgml 0.01 sec, 39,480 bytes
   %     library(quintus) compiled into quintus 0.00 sec, 23,896 bytes
   %    rewrite compiled into rewrite 0.00 sec, 35,336 bytes
   %    library(record) compiled into record 0.00 sec, 31,368 bytes
   %   rdf_parser compiled into rdf_parser 0.01 sec, 132,840 bytes
   %    library(gensym) compiled into gensym 0.00 sec, 4,792 bytes
   %   rdf_triple compiled into rdf_triple 0.00 sec, 39,672 bytes
   %  library(rdf) compiled into rdf 0.02 sec, 244,240 bytes
   % library(semweb/sparql_client) compiled into sparql_client 0.06 sec, 707,080 bytes
   true.
   ```
2. I execute my predicate:

   ```
   ?- buildQuery("Roma", Query, Row), write(Query).
   ERROR: uri:uri_query_components/2: Type error: `atomic' expected, found `[39,115,101,108,101,99,116,32,67,79,85,78,84,40,42,41,32,119,104,101,114,101,32,123,63,112,108,97,99,101,32,97,32,100,98,112,101,100,105,97,45,111,119,108,58,80,108,97,99,101,32,59,32,114,100,102,115,58,108,97,98,101,108,32,34,82,111,109,97,34,64,105,116,32,125,39]'
   ^  Exception: (12) ignore(http_open:parts_search([protocol(http), host('dbpedia.org'), port(80), path('/sparql/'), search([...])], _G1079)) ? creep
   ```

As you can see, it goes into an error.  The strange thing is that my Query value (I printed it using write/1) seems to be ok. In fact, if I translate the ASCII list into characters, its value is:

**'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "Roma"@it }'**

That is my original query (so it seems that the query string will build in the right way) but seems that the problem is in the others **sparql_query/3**  parameter and this is strange because it was copied from the previous post solution that works great.  Why? What am I missing?

Comment: `X="Roma", write(X)` ==> `[82,111,109,97]`. `X='"Roma"', write(X)` ==> `"Roma"`. `X="\"Roma\""` ==> `X = [34, 82, 111, 109, 97, 34].`.

Comment: you should use `End = [34, 64, 105, 116, 32, 125, 125]`. You have two `}}` in the end, not one. And 39 is a code for single quote, `"\'"`. It is not a part of the text, it is a delimiter around atom name. Similarly, `Q1` should start with `Q1 = [115, ...` (code for `"s"`). But instead of writing out the codes, you can just write `Q1 = "select COUNT(*) where .... "`, Prolog reads double-quoted strings as lists of character codes. Then, `sparql_query/3` works  I don't know what it expects. In you previous question you shown it used with atoms. use `atom_codes/2` to convert string <-> atom.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because the Query (first) argument of sparql_query/3 is an atom.  So, the simplest way to build your query is

```
atomic_list_concat([ 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "',
                     Place,
                     '"@en }'
                   ], Query),
sparql_query(Query, Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')] ).
```

Note that this only works as long as Place des not contain a double quote or other special character as defined by the SPARQL string syntax.